# Page renders differently with IE11 Dev tools open

Tags: web, internet-explorer-11, flexbox, lesshat

I have a strange problem: the site I build is using flexbox and LESSHAT. The strange thing I encounter is that it doesn't render correctly i.e. flexbox things seems to be omitted.

However, if I hit F12 and reload the page it is rendered is it should.

What is wrong?

**UPDATE** - This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="c header">
            <div class="box">Title</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box content">
            <div class="cv flex page">
                <div class="cl item">
                    <div class="cvl flex item-title">
                        <div class="cl">Item 1</div>
                        <div class="cl">
                            <div class="c button">1</div>
                            <div class="c button">2</div>
                            <div class="c button">3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cl item-more">
                        >>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="cl item">
                    <div class="cl flex item-title">
                        Item 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="cl item-more">
                        >>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="cl item">
                    <div class="cl flex item-title">
                        Item 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="cl item-more">
                        >>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Style CSS is compiled from this LESS file:

```
@import "lesshat";

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    width:100%;
    height: 48px;

    background: #0000ff;
    color: #fff;
}

.content {
    width:100%;
    background: #00ff00;
}

.page {
    width:100%;
    background: #00ffff;
}

.item {
    background: #ffff00;
    margin: 5px;
}

.button {
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.box {
    .display(flex);
}

.c {
    .display(flex);
    .justify-content(center);
    .align-items(center);
}

.cl {
    .display(flex);
    .align-items(center);
}

.cv {
    .display(flex);
    .flex-direction(column);
}

.flex {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: "What is wrong?" You didn't show your code. I would bet dollars to doughnuts that you invoke the flexbox stuff in the wrong place and when you reload, it gets loaded properly. But ... we'll never know.

Comment: How do I insert HTML or CSS code? It doesn't seem to work. Sorry, I'm new here as a poster.

Comment: Paste the code into your question, then select it again and use the "code" markup (the double curly braces {} ) to identify it as code.

Comment: Many thanks! Now the code is there:

Answer (score 0):

The reload and F12 solution seems to indicate one of the following issues:

- `<link>` or `<style>` tag for CSS outside of the `<head>`
- `document.write` via a downloaded `<script>`
- Asking for computed styles in related JavaScript code, via:

> offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight
>
> scrollTop/Left/Width/Height
>
> clientTop/Left/Width/Height
>
> getComputedStyle()

- Changing individual styles in related JavaScript code
- Getting and setting styles in a loop

**References**

- [Rendering: repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)